# How do I make wxAcceleratorTable work with wxFrame and wxTextCtrl?

Tags: wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I have a wxTextControl and a wxButton on a wxFrame, and I want Shift+Enter to cause the button to be clicked. The [wxAcceleratorTable documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_accelerator_table.html) says that this is possible:

"For example, you can use an accelerator table to enable a dialog with a multi-line text control to accept CTRL-Enter as meaning 'OK'."

I can't get it to work. Can you give me a short example of how to use wxFrame, wxTextControl, wxButton, and wxAcceleratorTable together?

Comment: Can you show here your code that is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that wxAcceleratorTable can only be used with wxEVT_MENU on wxGTK. So the code would have looked like this:

```
wxAcceleratorEntry shiftReturn(wxACCEL_SHIFT, WXK_RETURN, wxID_BACKWARD);
SetAcceleratorTable(wxAcceleratorTable(1, &shiftReturn));
Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &FindFrame::OnPrev, this, wxID_BACKWARD);
```

Instead, we decided to use native accelerators for GTK and OSX instead of wx accelerators, so that the keyboard shortcut would animate the target button. See [604cdb5](https://github.com/vslavik/poedit/commit/604cdb545498890a7a97ed2078cd36032ac5dca0), [b00a76e](https://github.com/vslavik/poedit/commit/b00a76e9809640bce7304810f81814a6f48b9eeb), and [91a8d2a](https://github.com/vslavik/poedit/commit/91a8d2a6e33e6fed0c211fd9932bac55667b385c) at [Poedit's GitHub page](https://github.com/vslavik/poedit).